# Excel formula query - quantity is between two value then value equals a given €amount

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

Doing some commercial modelling and was wondering if a formula exists to solve the following challenge:

If a quantity of an item equals between:

250 and 2499 then the value I want to show in a cell is €10,000.00

2500 and 4999 then the value I want to show in a cell is €15,000.00

5000 and 10000 then the value I want to show in a cell is €30,000.00

The quantity of items is persistent in a cell in Column C

Would really appreciate any help you could give

Many thanks

Jonny

Comment: How about this `=IF(AND(C1>250,C1<2499),10000,IF(AND(C1>2500,C1<4999),15000,IF(AND(C1>5000,C1<10000),30000,"")))`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the VLOOKUP formula with "TRUE" parameter ?

Try the following

In Cell D2 (and down below D3, D4, etc.) key-in the values 250, 2500, 5000, etc.
NOTE: these should be in ascending order.

In Cell E2 (and down below E3, E4, etc.) key-in the values 2499, 4999, 9999, etc.

In Cell F2 (and down below F3, F4, etc.) key-in the values 10000, 15000, 30000, etc.

Now, suppose say - in cell A2 you have your value to search
say for example  297

In cell C5 write the formula =VLOOKUP(A2,$D$2:$F$10,3,TRUE)

I feel this should get you your result.